# VBA to Open Office Basic convert trouble

Tags: vba, openoffice.org

Hi i'm trying to rewrite\convert this code to VBScript. In Excel 2013 work perfectly but in Open Office whatever i'm trying to search is throws there is no data(Nie znaleziono danych).

VBA Code:

```
Sub Znajdz()

Dim szukane As Variant

szukane = InputBox("Wpisz szukane słowo", "Wyszukaj")

If szukane = "" Then
MsgBox "Nie wpisałeś nic w okienku Wyszukaj", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation,"Brak danych"
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo blad

Cells.Find(What:=szukane, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Exit Sub

blad:

MsgBox "Nie znaleziono danych", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Brak wyników"

End Sub
```

My VBScript:

```
Sub Znajdz()

Dim szukane As Variant

szukane = InputBox("Wpisz szukane słowo", "Wyszukaj")

If szukane = "" Then
MsgBox "Nie wpisałeś nic w okienku Wyszukaj", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Brak danych"
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo blad

Cells.Find(What:=szukane, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=-4163, LookAt:= _
    1, SearchOrder:=1, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Exit Sub

blad:

MsgBox "Nie znaleziono danych", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Brak wyników"

End Sub
```

Help me i must use it in Open Office as macro

Comment: VBScript doesn't allow type declarations; change `Dim szukane As Variant` to just `Dim szukane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Office doesn't use VBA or VBScript for macros, it uses Open Office Basic.

The [OO Wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Macros/Can_I_use_my_Microsoft_Office_macros%3F) gives a method for executing VBA macros; maybe worth a look?

I've tried to convert it for you - give this a try?  I don't have OO to hand so can't test that it works...

```
Sub Znajdz()

Dim szukane As String
Dim oCell As Object
dim index As long
Dim Find As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
oSheet = StarDesktop.CurrentComponent.Sheets(0)

szukane = InputBox("Wpisz szukane słowo", "Wyszukaj")

If szukane = "" Then
    MsgBox "Nie wpisałeś nic w okienku Wyszukaj", MB_OK + MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, "Brak danych"
    End
End If

oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(1,1)
index = oCell.CellAddress.Sheet
Find = oSheet.createSearchDescriptor
Find.setSearchString(szukane)
oCell = oSheet.FindFirst(Find)
If Not IsNull(oCell) Then
    MsgBox "Found it at " & oCell.CellAddress.Column & oCell.CellAddress.Row
Else
    MsgBox "Not Found!"
Endif

End Sub
```

Comment: hmm.. and just one more thing you have use "& oCell.CellAddress.Column & oCell.CellAddress.Row" and how make to mark founded cell??

Comment: How to you mean mark it?  oCell.CellAddress has the column and row of the cell, so you can basically do anything you like with it at that point.  If you mean to select the cell itself, I would expect that you could add the line `thisComponent.getCurrentController.Select(oCell)` to enable a particular cell

Comment: That was exactly what I need.